# Trying to show all the results in Query

Tags: sql

I have a query issue as seen below, the problem is when it shows in the results it only shows questions with answers. I need the question to show if it has an answer or not. If there is not v.answer I need a.question to show in the results and null as the answers.

```
SELECT
    a.Question, v.Answer
FROM         
    Question a AS a 
FULL OUTER JOIN
    Answer v AS v ON a.ID = v.ID 
                  AND a.surveyID = v.surveyID
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: No, your query will show all questions.

Comment: a is a poor table alias for the questions table, and v isn't very good either. Use q for question, and a for answer.

Comment: Why are you aliasing your tables **twice**?

Comment: And **why** do you use `a` as alias for **Q**uestion, but `v` for **A**nswer?? The "Principle of Least Surprise" would recommend `q` for **Q**uestion, and `a` for **A**nswer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT Q.Question,
       A.Answer
FROM Questions Q LEFT JOIN Answers A ON Q.ID = A.ID
                                     AND Q.surveyID = A.surveyID;
```

This will return all the questions which have answers and if does not have an answer it will return `NULL`.

**[Simple Demo](https://rextester.com/NFDOUX14195)**